# Closed form of Gaussian CDF for integers

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I'm reviewing a paper that contains the following expression:

"$...=\int_{y-0.5}^{y+0.5}\mathcal{N}(t|0,\sigma)dt$ *, which can be evaluated in closed form*"

As far as I know, the CDF of the normal distribution has in general no closed-form expression. In this case, $\sigma$ is not known ahead of time and y is known to be an integer. However, this still shouldn't make it closed-form evaluable?! It's written with such naturalness that I'm wondering whether I'm overlooking something ...

Comment: What does "$\mathcal N$" refer to?  Would it be the *density* of a Normal distribution of variance $\sigma^2$, as is usual (and would be expected when appearing in such an integral)?  If so, then its evaluation is simply $\Phi((y+1/2)\sigma)-\Phi((y-1/2)/\sigma)$ where $\Phi$ is the standard Normal cdf (and that looks like a "closed form" to me).  Otherwise, what is it?

Comment: Dear @whuber: Yes, it's written in closed form, but that's not the same as evaluation in closed form as erf() requires numerical evaluation, that was the point I tried to make.

Comment: Considering that elementary functions like $\exp$ (which is involved in all non-integral powers) and $\cos$ require "numerical evaluation," too, might provide some useful context.  $\operatorname{erf}$ is no more difficult or time-consuming to evaluate than any of those.  I'm still trying to figure out whether you're asking about integrating the density or the CDF itself: could you address that question about the meaning of your notation?

Comment: @whuber I'm asking about the CDF, i.e. the result of the integration. I see your point and actually, it's sort of valid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your point. The so-called "closed form" of the CDF of a Gaussian, which in your case would be evaluated as part of this definite integral

$\Bigg[ \frac{1}{2} \Big[1 + \text{erf} \Big(\frac{t}{\sigma \sqrt{2}} \Big)\Big] \Bigg]_{t=y-0.5}^{t=y+0.5}$

does indeed depend on the [error function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) $\text{erf(x)}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{x} e^{-x^2} dx$, which must be computed using numerical methods. So in that sense it is not really closed form.

But it does *not* depend on any kind of sampling scheme (like Monte Carlo) to be evaluated, so in that sense it *is* closed form.

As for the standard deviation parameter $\sigma$, I can't see how you would get around evaluating the CDF without knowing it. Indeed, the conditional form the author wrote the PDF expression in - $\mathcal{N}(t|0,\sigma)$ - does suggest it is a dependency.

Comment: That's similar to my thoughts on the matter. Means it's unlikely I've overlooked something trivial, thanks a lot!